# Adding low-poly clothing

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

I have a bit of experience with Blender such as basic modelling and rigging. I've created my first character model before:

[image: lowpoly wolf-person girl thing...I don't know]

She's all rigged and ready for posing, but I'd like to know what the best route is to add clothes to her. I'd like it so that I can easily swap the clothing she's wearing as well. I've tried modelling clothes over top and then using fabric physics but most of the time I end up with awful clipping with the faces.

Comment: With low poly characters, usually, we select the faces that we want to have clothing on and press E to extrude them outwards. Then proceed with shaping and texturing them.

Comment: Also take a look at this video: https://www.blendernation.com/2017/05/30/sewing-low-poly-clothes-blender/

Answer (score 1):

I'd still go with the cloth physics approach but instead of using your character model as a base for the cloth simulation I'd create another simplified version of the parts that are going to be covered by clothes. This dummy then would get a simple displacement modifier with a low value so that it always stays over the character model's surface - like a cage.

Comment: Do I make it a new object? If so, do I just re-rig it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep your final poly count low, another approach might be to go with the traditional cloth effect; and then after it's behaving well, apply a Remesh modifier to it with a low octree depth. This will maintain the shape of the cloth, but with far fewer vertices. With proper usage of mirroring (higher in the modifier order than remeshing), you can even keep symmetry.

There are a lot of great ways to do this, though.